# Selenium 3 + JBehave?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave, selenium3

Does anyone use `JBehave` with `selenium 3.0` ? it looks like upgrade `selenium` version to 3.0 caused `JBehave` stops working.

All troubles are about -

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/thoughtworks/selenium/condition/ConditionRunner",

it seems this class has been removed on `selenium 3.0`.
Is there any work around ?

For example it is used on -

```
package org.jbehave.web.selenium;

    public SeleniumPage(Selenium selenium, ConditionRunner conditionRunner)
    {
        this.selenium = selenium;
        this.conditionRunner = conditionRunner;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer from the JBehave developer:

"We need to start a JBehave Web 4.0 branch that supports Selenium 3.0 "

So it looks like there is nothing to do with this issue for now.